# How can I deserialize a JSON array with LibGDX

Tags: json, libgdx

How can I deserialize a JSON array into a Java object with libgdx? I can use the libgdx Json serialization classes to deserialize a JSON object into a Java object but I don't know how to deal with an JSON array response. Surely there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is the array part of the bigger JSON response? If so, you can map the response into a single class having the array as a property and use [setElementType](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.html#setElementType-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) for automatic array deserialisation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Array](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html) class can handle JSON arrays representations. It can be just a field of class that you want to deserialize to:

```
    //Example of json string:
    String jsonString = "{\"array\":[{\"id\":1}, {\"id\":2}, {\"id\":3}]}";

    //Item class
    public class Item
    {
        public int id;
    }

    //class with Array
    public class ItemArray
    {
        public Array<Job> array;
    }

    //and deserialization:
    ... //getting JSON
    Json json = new Json();

    ItemArray itemArray = json.fromJson(ItemArray.class, jsonString);
```

If you want to use primitives please notice that there are also [FloatArray](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/FloatArray.html) and [IntArray](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/IntArray.html) classes in LibGDX

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop the json values and put it in a array yourself.

```
float[] elements = new float[jsonArray.get("arrayElement").size];
for (JsonValue element : jsonArray.get("arrayElement"))
{
    System.out.println(element.asString());
}
```

Not sure how you can put the array one on one into a java array. Neither do I have the time to figure out that one.